# Autorun for Mac?

Tags: macos, autorun, projector

I've got a Flash projector which I plan to distribute on CD. I'm making a projector for Mac and Windows. I know how to do Autorun on Windows, but I want to do so on Mac as well.

How does that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't. Mac OS 7–9 had a similar system but Mac OS X has nothing of the sort.

Your best bet is to make a nice Finder window design that makes it clear what to do.  [DropDMG](http://c-command.com/dropdmg/) may be useful.

Comment: Wait, so my CD can automount a dmg?

Comment: No, but you can create a DMG which you can then burn to CD.  The CD can optionally automatically open a Finder window when it's inserted; it just can't run anything.  (Take a look at how Apple's installer CD/DVDs work as an example.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no autorun in OSX anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set an application to autorun for security reasons. However you can set a Finder window to auto open on insert. I've seen a lot of CDs do this then have a "Click here to start" icon.

This is the terminal command to set it up on your diskimage before burning. discName should be the name of your disk image.

```
sudo bless -folder "/Volumes/discName" -openfolder "/Volumes/discName"
```

[More info here](http://tidbits.com/article/8464)

Answer (score -1):

There is an easy way to do it.  Just right-click the icon in the dock, chose "Options", then "Open at Login"
Then the selected app will launch every time OSX boots.

Comment: Please re-read the asker's request. They are *distributing* software, i.e., To other's systems.